# Problems installing gsl gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gsl

I can succesfully install the gsl library in my home directory, but when I try to install the gsl gem I get a big list of errors that I do not understand. I am wondering if someone could give me some idea why I could be getting those errors. I can say I have:

Installed gsl succesfully; at least that is what it looked like.
I pointed the path to gsl-config

This is what the error log looks like:

```
  Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
  ERROR:  Error installing gsl:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

  /home/ted/ruby-1.9.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb install gsl
  checking gsl version... 1.15
  checking gsl cflags... -I/home/ted/gsl-1.15/include
  checking for main() in -lcblas... no
  checking gsl libs... -L/home/ted/gsl-1.15/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
  checking for round()... no
  checking for rngextra/rngextra.h... no
  checking for qrngextra/qrngextra.h... no
  checking for ool/ool_version.h... no
  checking for tensor/tensor.h... no
  checking for jacobi.h... no
  checking for gsl/gsl_cqp.h... no
  checking for gsl/gsl_multimin_fsdf.h... no
  checking for gsl_poly_solve_quartic() in -lgsl... no
  checking for gsl_eigen_francis() in -lgsl... no
  checking for ndlinear/gsl_multifit_ndlinear.h... no
  checking for alf/alf.h... no
  checking rb-gsl version...1.14.7
  checking ruby version... 1.9.1
  checking for graph... no
  checking for narray.h... yes
  checking for tamu_anova/tamu_anova.h... no
  checking for main() in -ltamuanova... no
  creating Makefile

  make
  gcc -I. -I/home/ted/ruby-1.9.1/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/ted/ruby-1.9.1/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/ted/ruby-1.9.1/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_NARRAY_H  -I/home/ted/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/narray-0.6.0.1/. -I/home/ted/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux    -fPIC  -Wall -I../include  -I/home/ted/gsl-1.15/include  -o sf_bessel.o -c sf_bessel.c
  In file included from sf_bessel.c:13:
  ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:15:24: error: gsl/gsl_sf.h: No such file or directory
  ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:16:27: error: gsl/gsl_errno.h: No such file or directory
  ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:17:28: error: gsl/gsl_vector.h: No such file or directory
  In file included from ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:18,
                   from sf_bessel.c:13:
  /home/ted/gsl-1.15/include/gsl/gsl_math.h:23:25: error: gsl/gsl_sys.h: No such file or directory
  In file included from sf_bessel.c:13:
  ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:19:29: error: gsl/gsl_complex.h: No such file or directory
  In file included from ../include/rb_gsl.h:20,
                   from ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:21,
                   from sf_bessel.c:13:
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:23:28: error: gsl/gsl_matrix.h: No such file or directory
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:24:33: error: gsl/gsl_permutation.h: No such file or directory
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:25:32: error: gsl/gsl_ieee_utils.h: No such file or directory
  In file included from ../include/rb_gsl.h:20,
                   from ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:21,
                   from sf_bessel.c:13:
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:322: warning: type defaults to â€˜intâ€™ in declaration of â€˜gsl_complexâ€™
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:322: error: expected â€˜;â€™, â€˜,â€™ or â€˜)â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:324: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:325: error: expected â€˜)â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:326: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:328: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:329: error: expected â€˜)â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:330: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜*â€™ token
  ../include/rb_gsl_common.h:340: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜ary2complexâ€™
  In file included from ../include/rb_gsl.h:21,
                   from ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:21,
                   from sf_bessel.c:13:
  ../include/rb_gsl_math.h:24: error: expected â€˜)â€™ before â€˜(â€™ token
  In file included from ../include/rb_gsl.h:22,
                   from ../include/rb_gsl_sf.h:21,
                   from sf_bessel.c:13:
  ../include/rb_gsl_complex.h:19:34: error: gsl/gsl_complex_math.h: No such file or directory
```

...

```
  sf_bessel.c: In function â€˜rb_gsl_sf_bessel_zero_J1_eâ€™:
  sf_bessel.c:643: error: â€˜gsl_sf_bessel_zero_J1_eâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
  sf_bessel.c: In function â€˜rb_gsl_sf_bessel_zero_Jnuâ€™:
  sf_bessel.c:648: error: â€˜gsl_sf_bessel_zero_Jnuâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
  sf_bessel.c: In function â€˜rb_gsl_sf_bessel_zero_Jnu_eâ€™:
  sf_bessel.c:653: error: â€˜gsl_sf_bessel_zero_Jnu_eâ€™ undeclared (first use in this function)
  make: *** [sf_bessel.o] Error 1


  Gem files will remain installed in /home/ted/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gsl-1.14.7 for inspection.
  Results logged to /home/ted/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gsl-1.14.7/ext/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 21):

#### Install ruby GSL:

Ubuntu 11.10 includes a newer version (1.15) of libgsl0 that  **is not compatible with ruby/gsl :**

*Must install older version 1.14* for ruby/gsl to work:

```
curl -O http://mirror.veriportal.com/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.14.tar.gz
tar xvzf gsl-1.14.tar.gz
cd gsl-1.14
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo gem install --conservative --no-ri --no-rdoc gsl
```

Installation works OK and test on Ubuntu and Debian Squeeze:

```
Fetching: narray-0.6.0.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: gsl-1.14.7.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed narray-0.6.0.1
Successfully installed gsl-1.14.7
2 gems installed
```

Comment: On Mac OSX with homebrew, `brew install gsl114` will install gsl 1.14 for you

Comment: This mirror is no longer working. I've used this instead: ftp://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.14.tar.gz

Comment: The problem no longer exists in Ubuntu 14.04, just `sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev` and all will be fine.

Comment: @TamerShlash: I needed gsl 1.14 for my Jekyll/Octopress setup. Unfortunately, installing `libgsl0-dev` through apt-get doesn't solve the problem (on Ubuntu 14.04). I still have compilation errors when do `gem install gsl -v 1.14.7`. Download and install gsl 1.14 works for me.

Answer (score 10):

which OS are you on?

first you need to install `gsl` and `gsl-devel` RPMs on your OS as root...
e.g. on Fedora Linux:

```
sudo yum install -y gsl gsl-devel
```

then do the `gem install gsl` or `bundle install`

without the gsl-devel package, it will not find the correct C-header files.

You also need to make sure that those header files are installed in a location which is included in either the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or listed in /etc/ld.so.conf

Answer (score 7):

If you have:

- **GSL 1.16** (check with `gsl-config --version`) (e.g. in **Ubuntu 14.04**),
- **Ruby 2.1**

Then try https://github.com/siefca/rb-gsl -- it's tweaked for such configuration.
It should also work with Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 2.0.

If you're using bundler to manage gems in a project then put a line in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'gsl', :git => 'git://github.com/siefca/rb-gsl'
```

*Cheers!*

Answer (score 5):

For anyone still struggling to install this with the `gsl_matrix_complex_equal` issue.

If you have run `brew install gsl` which will as of this writing install 1.15 and then attempted to install the ruby bindings, you will potentially run into this problem.

Using this repo as your rb-gsl gem source solves the issue:
https://github.com/30robots/rb-gsl

However, if you have a newer version of rubygems, that repo makes a call to `Gem#searcher` which is a deprecated and now removed method.

My repo updates that call to use the `Gem::Specification` API:

https://github.com/whistlerbrk/rb-gsl

So in short:

`brew install gsl` on OSX

and in your Gemfile:

`gem 'gsl', :git => 'git://github.com/whistlerbrk/rb-gsl.git'`

Comment: This will try to install 1.14 gem?

Answer (score 5):

under ubuntu 13.04 this solves the problem:

`sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev`

no need to manually install an old version

Answer (score 2):

Attention it seems not working with Ruby 2.1.0.

For Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ruby 2.0.0:

```
cd ~
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.15.tar.gz
tar xvzf gsl-1.15.tar.gz
cd gsl-1.15
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Check if GSL 1.15 is correctly installed

```
gsl-config --version
```

Then install gem (gsl 1.15.3)

```
gem install gsl
```

Answer (score 2):

On my fresh install of **Mac OS X Yosemite**, I needed specifically 1.15.3, and homebrew can't get that for me (there is no `brew install gsl115`)

```
curl ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.15.tar.gz > gsl-1.15.tar.gz
tar xvzf gsl-1.15.tar.gz
cd gsl-1.15
./configure
make
sudo make install
gem install gsl
```

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 13.10, ruby 2.0.0 works fine next-

```
curl -O http://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.16.tar.gz
tar xvzf gsl-1.16.tar.gz
cd gsl-1.16
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo gem install --conservative --no-ri --no-rdoc gsl
```

Attention:
Ami Navon wrote-

**Must install older version 1.14 for ruby/gsl to work**

It is not actual now for gsl-1.16/ruby-2.0.0

Comment: Actually, on Mac OS X Yosemite new install, I needed these instructions but 1.15 ...  `curl -O http://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.15.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

`lsb_release -a` **Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS**
`ruby --version` **ruby 2.1.2p95**

---

**Important: Install gsl development package** (https://askubuntu.com/a/490475/121418)
`sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev`

Add this line in Gemfile
`gem 'rb-gsl'`

Install gem via Terminal
`bundle install`

---

Verify
`bundle show rb-gsl`
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rb-gsl-1.16.0.4

`gsl-config --version`
1.15

---

Use `require "gsl"` in ruby file if necessary

Answer (score 1):

This also works on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ruby 2.2.2
`sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev`