# Heroku/Rails: How to install the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gsl, tf-idf

I need to install the GSL library on Heroku running a Rails (4.0.2) app to use some gems that depend on it.

**Goal:**
Install the GSL library to work with [GSL](http://rubygems.org/gems/gsl) and [Similarity](http://rubygems.org/gems/similarity) gems in Heroku.

**Tried approaches:**

- [Installing Ruby / GSL in Heroku Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874776/installing-ruby-gsl-in-heroku-application): Heroku crashes after deploy. GSL gem is unable to find the lib. Trace: http://pastebin.com/CPcMUdCa
- [Tomwolfe's Heroku's Ruby buildpack adapted for using couchbase](https://github.com/tomwolfe/heroku-buildpack-gsl-ruby): Same issue.
- [Building Dependency Binaries for Heroku Applications](http://www.higherorderheroku.com/articles/using-vulcan-to-build-binary-dependencies-on-heroku/): Vulcan is deprecated. More info on [Heroku's Devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries) and on [Github](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan)

I've tried following these steps (compiling binaries):

- GSL 1.15 downloaded from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.15.tar.gz
- Uncompressed and `cd gsl-1.15`
- `./configure`
- `make clean`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`

It works on my local environment but not in Heroku. Heroku doesn't allow `sudo` but it allows access with `heroku run`. The problem is that the file system is ephemeral and the dyno will only live as long as your console session.

**Update:**

I've also tried building my own Heroku Buildpack but I couldn't make it work. I tried using **multipacks**.  I'm not a Heroku Buildpack expert so maybe it's the problem, **I'm learning more about it** to make a simple repository with an example and an extended explanation of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a heroku buildpack a couple months ago for 1.15 and 1.16

just do:

`heroku buildpacks:set git://github.com/gregory/heroku-gsl-buildpack.git#gsl-1.16`

or

`heroku buildpacks:set git://github.com/gregory/heroku-gsl-buildpack.git#gsl-1.15`

Answer (score 2):

I had to use gsl1.16 on heroku and here is how I solved it:

First added gsl1.16 buildpack to the lists of buildpacks like

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index:3 git://github.com/gregory/heroku-gsl-buildpack.git#gsl-1.16
```

Which adds to my list of buildpacks, in my case got nodejs and ruby already. Hence `--index=3`

Then had to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on heroku like

```
heroku config:set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/vendor/gsl/lib
```

which points to 1.16. Seen around that some people use `/app/vendor/gsl1/lib` but wasn't my case.

and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a [custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). Buildpacks allow you to define any additional dependencies outside of your project and package them with your slug which is used by the dynos. The buildpack you linked to (https://github.com/tomwolfe/heroku-buildpack-gsl-ruby) would be your best bet in getting everything working. I would open issues on their github repo if you are having issues, hopefully they can help you out

Comment: Thank you Dan. Actually I'm newbie with Heroktu Buildpacks so I'll try it first on my own (to learn) and notice you.

Comment: Hi again Dan. Now I know how it works (Buildpacks) but how I can implement it in my (started) current project? Thank you!

Comment: You may be able to switch buildpacks, but it is probably easier to just create a new app with the heroku and destroy your old one. It looks as though if you set the `BUILDPACK_URL` heroku will use that: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack

Comment: Yes! adding BUILDPACK_URL works to deploy/install: `heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/skozz/heroku-buildpack-gsl-ruby.git --app <<myapp>>` (I forked to change the GSL version to 1.14). Now the problem is after deploy: `/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gsl-1.15.3/lib/gsl.rb:2:in `require': libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/gsl-1.15.3/lib/rb_gsl.so (LoadError)` can't find the lib.

Comment: @skozz did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @Sixty4Bit i'm working on my own Buildpack supporting a updated GSL